# actions: c++ server, python client (smach)

Tags: python, c++, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Can I implement an action server in C++ and call it from a client in python (i.e. from a Smach script)? As far as I understand the ROS architecture, so long as they share the same .action file, this should work, no?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196949/actions:-c++-server,-python-client-(smach)/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2014-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. If both client libraries have support for actions and have access to the same action definition, it should work.

Python and C++ are both well used and supported.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-11-09**:
Ok, this is all as expected then! Thanks!

**Comment by [Fi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22677/fi/) on 2015-08-17**:
Hi; What about vice versa? As I have not completely understood it, would you please give me more details and example?

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2015-08-17**:
Vice versa will work as nicely. There is nothing special to do, just to implement a action server in a language and the client in another language. So long as the cores are ROS compatible, it will work (because the messages use the same ROS protocol).

**Comment by [Fi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22677/fi/) on 2015-08-17**:
would you please send me an example?

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2015-08-18**:
There is a reference tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib) which already explains it all.